# Error: ERROR processing ./governor-token.ts: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'blockConfirmations')

Tags: typescript, ethereum, solidity

I want to deploy my token smart contract (solidity) via typescript on the Rinkeby test network.

The command that fails is:

```
const governanceToken = await deploy("GovernanceToken", {
    from: deployer,
    args: [],
    log: true,
    // we need to wait if on a live network so we can verify properly
    waitConfirmations: networkConfig[network.name].blockConfirmations || 1,
  })
```

`Error: ERROR processing ./governor-token.ts: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'blockConfirmations')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow why the solution in the post doesn't work, but if I use the ContractsFactory instead and some awaits it works fine:

```
  const Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("GovernanceToken")
  const governanceToken = await Token.deploy()
  await governanceToken.deployed()
```